# Generating thumbnails in JSP

Tags: image, jsp, pagination, blob

What principle applies while generate thumbnails using JSP ?

Comment: You're writing the bytes of the image inline with the HTML in the same response! That is NOT going to work.

Comment: Why haven't you updated your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726078) instead?

Comment: what do i need to do to achieve paginated images from database ??